# Novell.directory.ldap

Tags: novell

I am currently reviewing a web service codes that is connected to NOVELL eDirectory. I am trying to find how did the codes connect with the Novell eDirectory but I wasn't able to find it.

The program is C#.net and it is using Novell.Directory.Ldap API

Answer (score 1):

Novell LDAP, for secure, it's port 636, you'll need an account in the eDir to bind with AND you will need a certificate from the eDir CA to access it. While you can change the settings to allow connection to the LDAP over 389 for lookup, you should not do authentication that way.

Answer (score 0):

Well on the eDirectory side, you can connect to the server it is pointing at, and use DSTrace to watch the LDAP connection and what it is asking for.

Comment: Thanks for your comment dude. I saw that the host parameter comes from ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("LDAPServer"). Does it mean that the host parameter comes from the web.config file in ASP.net? because I'm not really familiar with ASP.net